# Undirected graphical models with for discrete variables with hidden nodes - loglikelihood (The elements of statistical learning)

Tags: machine-learning, probability, hidden-markov-model, graphical-model, likelihood

I don't understand the equation of loglikelihood of the observed data in graphical models with hidden nodes that appears in "The Elements of Statistical Learning" (Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedmann, chapter 17.4.2)

[image]

In the equation we sum over possible values of $x_h$, but $x_h$ doesn't appear anymore in the equation. Where does this sum come from?

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). (See also the [second equation of slide 5](http://people.reed.edu/~jones/Courses/P02.pdf).)

Specifically the lower-case $x_{\mathcal{H}}$ you mention are supposed to refer to all possible/states values of the **h**idden random variables $X_{\mathcal{H}}$. To quote the authors:

> The sum over $x_{\mathcal{H}}$ means that we are summing over all possible $\{0,1\}$ values for the hidden units.

It is a common (albeit somewhat ambiguous) practice to refer to the (possible) values of a random variable denoted with an upper-case letter, e.g. $T, X, Y, Z$, using the corresponding lower-case letters, e.g. $t, x, y, z$ respectively. This allows us to talk about the event $\{ Y = y\}$ or the probability that the random variable $Y$ equals the value $y$, $\mathbb{P}(Y=y)$, without specifying which specific value $y$ we should consider. This is helpful when the particular value $y$ doesn't matter.

In this case, since we are summing over *all possible values* of the random variable(s) $X_{\mathcal{H}}$, every value in the sum is in some sense 'arbitrary', making the lower-case $x_{\mathcal{H}}$ convention for 'any particular value' of the random variable(s) $X_{\mathcal{H}}$ applicable here.